# Синие перемычки на материнской плате, для чего они?

Tags: железо

нашел на материнской плате такие перемычки, и стало интересно. что это такое? как они называются? для чего они? куда именно их вставлять? почему не на всех материнских платах расположены?

[image: 9999]

Comment: Джамперы они называются, насколько я знаю. Устанавливают какие-нибудь настройки. Читайте инструкцию к своей материнской плате. Лучше до того, как попробуете их переставить.

Comment: Под ними даже написано для чего они. Левая - сброс CMOS, правая - питание USB, похоже.

Answer (score 2):

На изображении:

Левый - Clear RTC, сбрасывает настройки CMOS (BIOS).

Правый - переключает системный блок в режим +5VSB(Standby) в котором питание на шину 5В подаётся даже когда компьютер выключен (для функций Wake-on-Mouse/Keyboard/Lan)

В документации к конкретной материнской плате будет расписан функционал каждого положения для джампера.

Answer (score 1):

Это перемычки (буквальный перевод слова jumper, есть хардварный сленг - "джампер"). Используются для различных настроек, но самый популярный джампер сейчас это, пожалуй, сброс CMOS (требуется если нет возможности войти в BIOS, например при неудачном разгоне процессора). Ранее перемычки были более распространены, но сейчас большинство настроек ушло в BIOS и управляется программно, что несравненно удобнее.